# htaccess rewrite issue adding directory

Tags: .htaccess

I am stumped on this htaccess write rule.

I currently have this rule functioning:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /item\.php\?pid=([a-z0-9]+)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^item\.php$ http://www.example.com/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^([-a-z0-9]+)$ /item.php?pid=$1 [NC,L]
```

Original url:

```
http://www.example.com/item.php?pid=2015-hyundai-genesis-coupe
```

enabling this url:

```
http://www.example.com/2015-hyundai-genesis-coupe
```

What I require is a url like this:

```
http://www.example.com/item/2015-hyundai-genesis-coupe
```

I tried a bunch of things with no success.  Anyone familiar with this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your htaccess to this instead:

```
Options -Multiviews

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /item\.php\?pid=([a-z0-9]+)\ HTTP/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^item\.php$ http://www.example.com/item/%1? [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^item/([-a-z0-9]+)$ /item.php?pid=$1 [NC,L]
```

You may or may not need the `Options` line. That's to ensure that mod_negotiation doesn't supercede mod-rewrite and map `/item` to `/item.php` before mod_rewrite can rewrite the request.

Additionally, you may need to make sure you have absolute links in your item.php page, otherwise they won't work because you're changing the relative URI base by making it `/item/` instead of `/`. You can also add this to the header of your page:

```
<base href="/" />
```